# Find $J_f$ of a function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x,y)=f(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}
x^2+y^2\\ 
2xy
\end{bmatrix}$.

- Find $J_f$.
- Find $\text{det}J_f$.
- Explain where we can apply the inverse function theorem in $\Bbb R^2$.
- For each point $x_0\in\Bbb R^2$, write down what the inverse function theorem says about the inverse $g$.
- Is $g$ differentiable?

**My try:**

First we have to, $$J_f(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}
2x & 2y\\ 
2y & 2x
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $\text{det}(J_f)=4x^2-4y^2$.

- We have to apply the inverse function theorem for all points $ (x, y) \in \Bbb R ^ 2 $ such that $ x^2\neq y^2 $.

What I do not understand is the other question about $ g $ because in the theorem nothing comes out about some function $ g $, could someone help me with the function $ g $, to try to ask the other question, to see if that $ g $ is differentiable.

Comment: The determinant is $4x^2-4y^2$.

Comment: Yes! Ty :D. @MichaelHoppe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inverse Function Theorem (I.V.F.) does say something about the inverse function. Instead of explicitly giving the inverse function itself, it tells us what the total differential (Jacobian) is in terms of the original function , which means the inverse is differentiable and you can obtain the total differential without even knowing the inverse.

Let $f\left(p\right)=q$ at which $\det J_f\left(p\right)\neq 0$. According to I.V.F, the Jacobian matrix is given by
$$
J_g\left(x,y\right)=\left(J_f\left(g\left(x,y\right)\right)\right)^{-1},
$$
where $g$ is a **local** inverse defined on a neighborhood of $q$.

You don't have to know what exactly $g$ is if you simply want to compute $J_g\left(x,y\right)$. The point is you need to recognize to what value $g$ sends $\left(x,y\right)$. We illustrate it as follows.

Put $p_1=\left(1,0\right),p_2=\left(0,1\right),p_3=\left(-1,0\right),p_4=\left(0,-1\right)$. Note that $$f\left(p_1\right)=f\left(p_2 \right)=f\left(p_3\right)=f\left(p_4\right)=\left(1,0\right)$$ and $\det J_f\left(x,y\right)\neq 0$ at each of these four points, so according to the I.V.F., there exist four local inverses $g_i:V_i\to U_i$, where $V_i$ is an open neighborhood of $\left(1,0\right)$ while $U_i$ is an open neighborhood of $p_i$.
Thus, notice that $$\left(J_f\left(x,y\right)\right)^{-1}=\frac{1}{4x^2-4y^2}\begin{bmatrix}
2x &-2y\\ 
-2y &2x
\end{bmatrix},$$
so we obtain
$$
J_{g_1}\left(1,0\right)=\left(J_f\left(p_1\right)\right)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} &0\\ 
0 &\frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
J_{g_2}\left(1,0\right)=\left(J_f\left(p_2\right)\right)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &\frac{1}{2}\\ 
\frac{1}{2} &0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
J_{g_3}\left(1,0\right)=\left(J_f\left(p_3\right)\right)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{2} &0\\ 
0 & -\frac{1}{2} 
\end{bmatrix},
$$
$$
J_{g_4}\left(1,0\right)=\left(J_f\left(p_4\right)\right)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &-\frac{1}{2}\\ 
-\frac{1}{2} &0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Does it make sense?

**Edition.** Thank Michael Hoppe for pointing out a mistake and I have revised this post. In addition, I supplement an example to make clear what I have tried to say.

Comment: For your reference, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: Since the function $ f $ is a continuously differentiable function, then we can say that $ g $ is a differentiable function, right? By the theorem.

Comment: Yap. You are right.

Comment: Ty so much :D...

Comment: To show that it is continuously differentiable at $ \Bbb R ^ 2 $. We have to prove that the partial derivatives are continuous at $ \Bbb R ^ 2 $. But we have that $ f_x (x, y) =\begin{bmatrix}
2x  \\ 
2y  
\end{bmatrix} $ y $ f_y (x, y) =\begin{bmatrix}
2y  \\ 
2x 
\end{bmatrix} $ And clearly those functions fulfill $ \lim _ {(x, y) \to (x_0, y_0)} f_x (x, y) = f_x (x_0, y_0) $ y $  \lim _ {(x, y) \to (x_0 , y_0)} f_y (x, y) = f_y (x_0, y_0) $. I'm right?

Comment: yeah u r right.

Comment: I strongly doubt that $J_g\left(x,y\right)=\left(J_f\left(x,y\right)\right)^{-1}$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I've revised my answer. Hope it would make much sense.